# How to build a daily history from a set of rows in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime

I have a simple SQLite table that records energy consumption all day long. It looks like that:

```
rowid       amrid       timestamp   value     
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1           1           1372434068  5720      
2           2           1372434075  0         
3           3           1372434075  90        
4           1           1372434078  5800      
5           2           1372434085  0         
6           3           1372434085  95
```

I would like to build a simplified history of the consumption of the last day by getting the closest value for every 10 minutes to build a CSV which would look like:

```
date              value
----------------  ---------- 
2013-07-01 00:00          90
2013-07-01 00:10         100
2013-07-01 00:20         145
```

As for now I have a request that allows me to get the closest value for one timestamp:

```
SELECT *
FROM indexes
WHERE amrid=3
ORDER BY ABS(timestamp - strftime('%s','2013-07-01 00:20:00'))
LIMIT 1;
```

How can I build a request that would do the trick to get it for the whole day?
Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me define "closest value" as the first value after each 10-minute interval begins.  You can generalize the idea to other definitions, but I think this is easiest to explain the idea.

Convert the timestamp to a string value of the form "yyyy-mm-dd hhMM".  This string is 15 characters long.  The 10-minute interval would be the first 14 characters.  So, using this as an aggregation key, calculate the `min(id)` and use this to join back to the original data.

Here is the idea:

```
select isum.*
from indexes i join
     (select substr(strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H%M', timestamp), 1, 14) as yyyymmddhhm,
             min(id) as whichid
      from indexes
      group by substr(strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H%M', timestamp), 1, 14)
     ) isum
     on i.id = isum.whichid
```

Comment: Typo towards the end of line 6? Should end `...1, 14)`?

Comment: Many thanks, your idea works just great. Here is my final statement: 
`select  substr(strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', timestamp, 'unixepoch'), 1, 15) || '0' as date,
 value
from indexes i join
     (select substr(strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M', timestamp, 'unixepoch'), 1, 11) as yyyymmddhhm,
             min(rowid) as whichid
      from indexes
      where amrid = 1
      and   date(timestamp, 'unixepoch') = '2013-07-01'
      group by substr(strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M', timestamp, 'unixepoch'), 1, 11)
     ) isum
     on i.rowid = isum.whichid;`